# How to ensure proper message formatting?

Tags: php, html, symfony, roundcube, hmail-server

I'm using a Symfony translation file and Mailer Bundle to send an email that serves in password resetting in the following format:

```
      <trans-unit id="resetting.email.message">
        <source>resetting.email.message</source>
        <target>
          Hello %username%!
        
          To reset your password - please visit %confirmationUrl%

          Regards,
          the Team.
        </target>
      </trans-unit>
```

I'm using **hMailServer** as a local mail server and **Roundcube** for email display. The problem is that I am receiving the email in the following format:

```
Hello %username%! To reset your password - please visit %confirmationUrl% Regards, the Team.
```

(The variables *username* and *confirmationUrl* are substituted I'm just showing how the email is being sent). 
As you can see, the line breaks are ignored. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Break the translation unit into smaller parts and add HTML line breaks in your template ?

Comment: Are you sending it as a HTML email or a plain text email? If it's a HTML email, then you need to add the line breaks using HTML (`<br>`) or use (`<p>...</p>`) for the different paragraphs. Ordinary line breaks aren't rendered in a HTML view.

Comment: Thank you guys I solved it. So instead of sending a HTML email, I switched off the HTML display in roundcube and the line breaks are being formatted without the need to add HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of sending a HTML email, I switched off the HTML display in roundcube and the line breaks are being formatted without the need to add HTML tags. 
(HTML display was on by default)